# How to detect Windows XP or Windows 2000 OS to run a CVI executable

Tags: compiler-construction, cvi, labwindows

I am using NI LabWindows CVI 8.1 to compile and build a executable program which I need to run on either Windows XP and Windows 2000 OS. I use Windows XP to compile and build the executable. The info I have so far is that I need to place some statement as follows:

```
#ifdef (windows xp)
//then specify path as C:\WINDOWS\system32
#elif (windows NT)
//then specify path as C:\WINNT\system32
#endif
```

I need to know what is the exact syntax and where to place it (like which header or source file to place it).

Comment: XP can have a system path of C:\winnt (default case for upgrades from Win2k I think.)  And C: might not be the system drive.  And a crazy user could probably redirect Windows to somewhere else.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to call APIs:

http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361F-01/lvexcodeconcepts/ex_3_call_the_win32_api/

Then, try GetSystemDirectory:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724373(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Indeed—do not hard code `C:` anything!  I don't have a single system with the default directory.  For example, the most used system has the system directory `E:\WINNT55SP2\SYS32`.